# How to get data from observable stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following observable:

```
public selectedObjectsIds$ = of();
```

Also another stream:

```js
this.reportMode$.pipe(
  filter((state: ReportMode) => state === ReportMode.close)
)
 .subscribe(() => {
    // Get here data from selectedObjectsIds$ 
 });
```

I want to get data from `selectedObjectsIds$` if first stream filtered true.

How to do that?

I know only way with:

```js
combineLatest([this.reportMode$, selectedObjectsIds$])...
```

Comment: Just switchMap after the filter should do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
this.reportMode$.pipe(
  filter((state: ReportMode) => state === ReportMode.close),
  // mergeMap will be trigger only if any state === ReportMode.close
  mergeMap((data: ReportMode) => selectedObjectsIds$) 
).
 subscribe((selectedIds: any) => {
  // ...
})
```